# Stop Silverlight 5 from throwing WebExceptions for non-200 status codes?

Tags: silverlight, rest, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to develop a client application that calls a RESTful web service. As part of a RESTful design, the service uses a variety of HTTP status codes to communicate state back to the caller.  For instance, if I request a resource that doesn't exist, the service responds with a 404 status code. Likewise, if I pass in malformed parameters, the service responds with a 400 (Bad Request) status code.  Silverlight 5 automatically converts these into WebExceptions.  Is there anyway I can get SL to not throw exceptions but return a legitimate response object with the status code, etc set to the what was received so that I can decide how to handle the response in my code?

(To further clarify, it appears this is only the case for status codes in the 400 and 500 ranges.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no solution to avoid exceptions. Worse than that, it might be hard or even impossible to get the actual HTTP code (I'm not certain there, I haven't tried too hard).

You'll probably want to develop an HTTP request tool that traps `WebException` and provide an error status to the caller.

Comment: Fortunately, the WebException exposes the HttpWebResponse object that was received and this gives us the StatusCode, StatusReason et al.  I'm currently doing exactly what you described (catching the exception and converting it back to a response). It would be nice if there was a way to eliminate the overhead of SL converting the response to an exception, throwing it and handling it only to convert it back to the original response that was received so I can decide how to react to the status.

Comment: Thanks for the details, that's good to know (as I said earlier, I haven't searched too much).